# Why is my system freezing when I switch users

Tags: lightdm

Hello I've recently upgraded from 13.04 to 13.10 64bit.

I'm running AMD graphics with the proprietary drivers.

I have two user accounts. Mine(administrator) and my girlfriend's(standard)

My girlfriend clicks "switch user" from my lock screen and logs in fine.

I then try to click "switch user" from her lock screen and everything goes black. Then the monitor blinks on and off with just a single cursor. I have no way to access the terminal, the system is unresponsive and I have to hit the power button. Even `ctrl + alt + f4` or `ctrl + alt + t` doesn't get me a terminal. When I press the power button on my system, it does start printing out the shutdown sequence on the monitor.

Here is my .xsession-errors

```
Script for ibus started at run_im.
Script for auto started at run_im.
Script for default started at run_im.
```

Here is hers:

```
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd respawning too fast, stopped
init: logrotate main process (4726) killed by TERM signal
init: upstart-dbus-session-bridge main process (4865) terminated with status 1
init: gnome-settings-daemon main process (4843) terminated with status 1
init: gnome-session main process (4852) terminated with status 1
init: unity-panel-service main process (4863) killed by KILL signal
```

I found some advice in a forum to look for `at-spi2-registryd` in my system logs. Perhaps it will be useful.

executing this: `sudo grep -r at-spi2-registryd /var/log/*` 
produces this:

```
/var/log/lightdm/x-1-greeter.log:** (at-spi2-registryd:4384): WARNING **: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
/var/log/lightdm/x-1-greeter.log:** (at-spi2-registryd:4384): WARNING **: Unable to register client with session manager
/var/log/lightdm/x-2-greeter.log.old:** (at-spi2-registryd:7447): WARNING **: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
/var/log/lightdm/x-2-greeter.log.old:** (at-spi2-registryd:7447): WARNING **: Unable to register client with session manager
/var/log/lightdm/x-0-greeter.log:** (at-spi2-registryd:1378): WARNING **: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
/var/log/lightdm/x-0-greeter.log:** (at-spi2-registryd:1378): WARNING **: Unable to register client with session manager
/var/log/lightdm/x-0-greeter.log.old:** (at-spi2-registryd:1357): WARNING **: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
/var/log/lightdm/x-0-greeter.log.old:** (at-spi2-registryd:1357): WARNING **: Unable to register client with session manager
```

Here are my logs lightdm logs:

[lightdm.log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6390107/)

[x-0-greeter.log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6390110/)

[x-0.log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6390114/)

[x-1-greeter.log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6390117/)

[x-1.log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6390138/)
[x-2.log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6390120/)

Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: sounds like a bug to me, is it reported on launchpad?

Comment: I'm not sure. I've done some googling but haven't found anything exactly like my problem.

Comment: I have the same issue on Ubuntu 13.10 on a laptop with nvidia video card, using nouveau driver

Comment: Have you tried purging the proprietary driver, do you have the same problem with the default open source driver?

Comment: I found a similar bug report. If you are having this problem, you can subscribe to it and provide feedback if needed. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/884331

Answer (score 3):

I fixed the problem but I'm not sure what caused it.

I renamed /var/lib/lightdm/.Xauthority to /var/lib/lightdm/.Xauthority-bak
I did the same thing in my home directory.

```
sudo mv /var/lib/lightdm/.Xauthority /var/lib/lightdm/.Xauthority-bak
mv ~/.Xauthority ~/.Xauthority-bak
```

Then I restarted lightdm

```
sudo service lightdm stop
sudo service lightdm start
```

Works fine now. One of the files was corrupted, but I'm not sure which one fixed it.

Comment: Nevermind. It worked for a day but its not working now.

Comment: ctrl-alt-f7/f8 may work for you as a workaround. Have you tried that? If deleting `.Xauthority` and restarting `lightdm` worked for a day, I think the real question is what is crashing/corrupting the X session. Your `xsesion-errors` normal, but hers are not. It _might_ be a lightdm bug, or aconflict in config files left over from 13.04, but it might be something else. Is there more you can edit into your question about what else is going on or what software you're using, etc before it starts happening again?

Comment: Btw, that lightdm bug report is old, is filed against an EOL version of Ubuntu, and from looking at the posted log files, although the effect is the same, it doesn't look like the same problem you are having. You might search for/file a new bug.

Comment: Do any logs have this line: `Failed to switch to greeter:` or `Failed to get system bus:`?

Comment: I didn't find those in the logs using this command: `sudo grep -r "Failed to switch to greeter:" /var/log/*` Also I've posted a screenshot of my .Xauthority file... it looks corrupt.

Comment: Thanks. I may have some more questions, although everything I've looked at so far suggests a bug. `.Xauthority` is a binary file, so using `cat` to display it will always look like that. I edited out the screenshot as not needed.

Comment: You are using `switch user` from `gnome-screensaver` (the lock scren). What happens when you use the Unity menu to switch users? (Power button, then click the user you want.) And what happens when you use ctrl-alt-f8 to switch to her account, then ctrl-alt-f7 to switch back to yours? If possible, please remove the .Xauthority file (you can use `rm`. It's recreated when you log back in) and restart before trying each option.

Comment: A couple more things: run `su -l other-user-name-here`. This logs in the other user without starting a 2nd x-session. Any problems? Look in `/var/log/lightdm`, especially files starting with `x-1` and `x-2`. Look for errors, especially related to authorization, user names, etc. Ignore `dbus`, `dconf` errors. Also, btw, the `at-spi2-registryd` warnings are normal.

Comment: Ok, I've verified that switching users using the Unity menu has the same result as using the screensaver menu. Pressing 'ctrl - alt - f8' resulted in a blank screen and I had to restart the system. I think I'll pastebin my logs and post them.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11436/discussion-between-zerodivide-and-chaskes)

Answer (score 0):

am have same problem on lowend netbook. most likely when you go to swich users is't logout from first so you have resoult to running two xsession on same time. 
frist logout, then login to other account.

Comment: Yeah logging out avoids the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From `x-2.log`:

```
Loading extension ATIFGLRXDRI
(EE) 
(EE) Backtrace:
```

That's the ATI/AMD video driver causing the second X-server to crash.

You may have a problem caused by upgrading. I would say you have two options after completely backing up your data:

1. Completely purge the proprietary driver and then reinstall it.

   If that doesn't fix it,
2. Do a clean install of 13.10.

With either option, you might try the open source driver with 13.10 and see how it goes for a while before re-installing the proprietary driver.

Comment: I switched to the open source driver then purged fglrx. Still have the same problem. I'll reinstall tomorrow, but I'll be installing Mint instead of Ubuntu. I've had it on my laptop for a while and wanted to change anyways. This seems like a good opportunity to do it.

Comment: If you installed fglrx from amd site rather than additional drivers, you need to [purge fglrx](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Raring_Installation_Guide) and reinstall a few things to make the open source driver work right. I still think it's likely a problem from the upgrade and a clean install of either Ubuntu or Mint will take care of it. If it goes away after that, please remember to accept or upvote the answer. ;) Good luck with it.

Comment: I had the exact same issue as the OP from a clean install, so I don't think that is the solution...

Comment: @rft183 Interesting, thanks. So it's back to filing a new bug report. Still, the OP may have a different experience.